# Dynamically create CLR object from the string

Tags: c#, .net

As a result of some service action I'm getting in the result property string with value `"MyNamespace.Models.Car"`

How can I dynamically create the object (empty) from this string value? Or how else can I dynamically recognize clr type from this string?

```
var result = service.getSomeData(req);
result.CustomVal holds the value of "MyNamespace.Models.Car";
```

Note that I cannot change the service.

Comment: Do you have `Car` class created in `MyNamespace.Models` namespace?

Comment: yes I do have Car in the Models namespace

Comment: Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: If you are dealing with weakly typed services, there is a helper class for you: ExpandoObject. At it's core it is little more then some Syntax Sugar for using a Dictionary<string, object> with some Change Notificaiton. But it certainly helps when you have to deal with you average, weakly typed webservice.

Answer (score 0):

With reflection you can find all types in assembly, then use `Activator.CreateInstance` [Documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2)